# sagemath 3d plot tumble (enhanced spin)?

Tags: sagemath

I am experimenting with SageMath today; I am new to SageMath.

In cocalc.com I found this demo:

```
show(icosahedron(color='green', opacity=.5, mesh=3), spin=1)
```

Are there different axes that you can configure it to spin around, so that it'd be possible to get it to do something like "tumble"?

Comment: You might want to ask on Stack Overflow. This is more of a programming question than a math question.

Comment: I would recommend posting on [Ask Sage](https://ask.sagemath.org) or [sage-support](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sage-support).

Comment: Reposted as: [Ask Sage question 48989: Possible to enhance spin-feature of 3D plot?](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/48989)